# Mysql UTF-8 unexpected character collation

Tags: mysql, linux, utf-8

After being a stackoverflow user for several years I never felt need to ask a question myself.  Hopefully someone will point me at something now. Here is the issue:

Here is the create table query (I stripped out foreign keys):

```
CREATE TABLE train_seat_class (
  id smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  code varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  capacity tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  img varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  supplier_id int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  enabled tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  int_descr varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  sort_order smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '10',
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY code_supplier_idx_idx (code,supplier_id),
  KEY supplier_id_idx (supplier_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=115 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PACK_KEYS=0 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

The problem appeared when I've been importing new data into this table. These 2 queries resulted in unexpected Duplicate entry on unique key:

```
insert into train_seat_class (code, capacity, img, supplier_id, enabled, int_descr, sort_order)
  values ('Л', 1, null, 8, 1, 'Bed', 10);

insert into train_seat_class (code, capacity, img, supplier_id, enabled, int_descr, sort_order)
  values ('М', 1, null, 8, 1, 'Cabin', 10);
```

It was a bit confusing, while results of the following query were just mind blowing:

```
SELECT * FROM train_seat_class y where code = 'М';
```

Results:

```
+----+------+----------+------+-------------+---------+-----------+------------+
| id | code | capacity | img  | supplier_id | enabled | int_descr | sort_order |
+----+------+----------+------+-------------+---------+-----------+------------+
| 96 | Л    |        1 | NULL |           8 |       1 | Bed       |         10 |
+----+------+----------+------+-------------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

This record was created by the first insert above. It was noticed under the following environment: MySQL server 5.5.31-1~dotdeb.0 (Debian), Debian Linux (2.6.32-5-amd64).

On PC using WINDOWS OS it worked as expected (both inserts successful).

I assumed it has something to do with collations, but changing it from utf8_unicode_ci to utf8_general_ci didn't help. The characters in question have the following UTF-8 codes: 041B, 041C.

Another assumption was that server ignores utf-8 encoding and uses only a single byte in collation, but it can't be true, because 4 out of 6 records like mentioned above were successfully inserted, and there are characters with the same 1st byte as in these two.

The problem is very confusing to me right now, and any help is appreciated. My apologies for long wall of text (I tried to make as descriptive as I could) or possibly bad language (not a native language).

If there is any more data you need, feel free to ask or correct me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, now disregard all that was said above. Solved it by using more strict collation for code column (utf8_bin).

I would've just deleted the question, but who knows, maybe someone will find this useful.